# Yii - SQL Query with having issue

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with column date_reservation

When I use simple SQL query function to get the total items between two dates using HAVING, it results correctly but when I use model of that table and set the criteria using CDBCriteria it says that column date_reservation defined in having clue does not exist.

Here is my SQL Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `booking` 
WHERE id_domain='1' 
AND  lang='fr'
HAVING date_reservation >'2011-06-06 00:00:00' 
AND date_reservation< '2011-06-10 00:00:00'
```

and Here is Query Generated by CDBCriteria

> Error in querying SQL: SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `booking` `t` WHERE 
>   id_domain='1' AND  lang='fr'  HAVING
>   date_reservation >'2011-06-08
>   00:00:00' AND date_reservation
>   <'2011-06-10 00:00:00'

Any help?

Comment: why are you putting the date criteria in "having" instead of the WHERE clause, btw?

Comment: also, can you show how you are generating the CDBCriteria?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `SELECT *` and `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

When using `SELECT COUNT(*)`, `date_reservation` hasn't been included in the query.